# Bundled (optimized) styles aren't recognized by browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, styles, bundle

I tried to use Bundle in my asp.net MVC4 project when it is debug mode all it ok, but when I try to use optimized mode something strange happens.

It's my bundle configuration:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/content/admin/css").Include("~/Content/css/AdminPage.css",
                                                                                    "~/Content/MarkItUp/MarkItUp.css",
                                                                                    "~/Content/MarkItUp/style.css",
                                                                                    "~/Content/jqTreeThemes/apple/style.css",
                                                                                    "~/Content/css/popup_window.css",
                                                                                    "~/Content/css/fullcalendar.css",
                                                                                    "~/Content/jHtmlArea/jHtmlArea.css"));
```

and it's how I use it on my page:

```
@section header
{
    @Styles.Render("~/content/admin/css");
}
```

so, when I use

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

for example, Firefox gets style as a script, I can see this in Net tab of FireBug. 
(http://grab.by/nZ0Y)

and thats why my stales don't have any effects.

Can somebody explain my why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `ScriptBundle` (used for scripts), use  `StyleBundle` (for styles).

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/admin/css").Include("~/Content/css/AdminPage.css","~/Content/MarkItUp/MarkItUp.css","~/Content/MarkItUp/style.css","~/Content/jqTreeThemes/apple/style.css","~/Content/css/popup_window.css","~/Content/css/fullcalendar.css","~/Content/jHtmlArea/jHtmlArea.css"));
```

Comment: xD, thanks) I found out the problem on the next morning, it was so long coding process!)